# Some Assets images missing from matrix fields after upgrade

Tags: matrix, assets, pixelandtonic, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

Upgraded from 2.5.2 to 2.10.1 and now some of the Assets stored images are missing from Matrix fields in some entries (The rows are blank with just a caption left behind and the 'Add file' button. I thought it might be down to having to up date the indexes in Assets. When I run the update I get a message saying

> There are some entries in the database that are out of date - please select the ones that you want to delete below –

And then a list of about 50 files. When I navigate to these files in the ftp some are present and some aren't. I didn't want to delete these references in case it caused more problems.

Comment: Do it. **But back up your database first**, and be ready to restore it.

Comment: Thanks. I've just done it. Data all looks fine, but still have the same problem. I wonder if it's more of a Matrix issue?

Comment: Did you update the plugins first? I typically do that then EE

Comment: No, I updated EE then the plugins.